# Wrapping a React component and passing through its props – with type safety

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to create a generic React component that essentially wraps another (arbitrary) component, and that exposes the wrapped component's props in a type safe way. Essentially, I want a caller to be able to write:

```
<Wrapper type={WrappedComponent} foo="bar" bar="baz" />
```

Where `foo` and `bar` are both props of the `WrappedComponent`. If the caller were to pass another prop that isn't present on `WrappedComponent`, they should see a type error.

Is this possible? I've tried a few things using `React.ComponentProps` and friends, but I have only got quite cryptic type errors back that I don't really understand as someone quite new to TypeScript.

Comment: It sounds like the Higher-Order components https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html . The question is, why do you need to do that? If you need to reuse some code, you should use custom hooks or wrap another component with child prop <Wrapper><WrappedComponent  foo="bar" bar="baz" /></Wrapper>

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```js
const Test = (props: { foo: string }) => <p>123</p>;

const Wrapper = <Props,>({ type }: { type: FunctionComponent<Props> } & Props) => {
  return null;
};

const ok = <Wrapper type={Test} foo="hello" />; // ok
const error = <Wrapper type={Test}  />; //  foo prop is missing
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZVaKm)
Please see my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) for more information
THe goal is to infer Props from passed component (type).